# Doing what ImageAdjust does for a group of images

Tags: image-processing

```
img = Import["flower.png"];
ImageAdjust[img, 0, {.00000002, .00000009}];
```

I know how `ImageAdjust` works and it is perfect for one image, but if I have more than one image, I cannot adjust all images together. Can anyone please help me do this?

Comment: Adjust all images for what ? Do you want the same adjustment for all or different adjustments ?

Comment: Is `Map` the answer?

Comment: You can import all images and make a list: `lst={img1, img2,...}` and then use the advise of @Kuba: `Map[ImageAdjust[#, 0, {.00000002, .00000009}]&, lst]`. As the result all images of the list will be adjusted with the same parameters.

Comment: You can also use Do[stuffTo[picture], {picture, listOfPictures}]

Comment: Thank you @AlexeiBoulbitch

Comment: list = {"img1.png","img2.png","img3.png"};
Map[ImageAdjust[#,0,{0.0000002,0.00000009}]&,list]
This code gives me error, but if I used only one image then it is perfectly work. seeking for help.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the comments, it seems you're just looking for `Map`.

```
list = {"img1.png","img2.png","img3.png"};
Map[ImageAdjust[Import[#],0,{0.0000002,0.00000009}]&, list]
```

You might want to read more from the [Ways to Apply Functions chapter of the Elementary Introduction.](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/25-ways-to-apply-functions.html)